# Scraping sec filings

Tags: finance, python, scraping

I'm trying to scrap all the historical filings of a particular Central Index Key (CIK) using python but I get http error codes.

First, I got 403 error, I resolved by using requests session and timing the requests every 5 seconds.

Now, I get http 400 after processing 30-40 requests. Not sure how to resolve this.

I have set the user-agent field as well.

Comment: Can you give us an idea of which website you are looking at?

Comment: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1043298/

Comment: Just to be clear, are you trying to recursively download all the files within that folder ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are scraping successfully but then it stops working, then you are getting your IP address blocked. This is an anti-scraping measure done by the server.

You'll need to slow down your scraping with a sleep statement (or switch IP addresses).

Here is a basic example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46471556/2327328

But you can also devise more robust solutions, that use python's `while` to check for a valid status code, and if not, then sleep an increasing amount of time.

Comment: I tried with a 5min interval and still it fails..I believe they are blocking it.